# How can I create google map this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I create this page ?

http://www.kiwicollection.com/search/map

- icon loading marker
- sidebar
- popup dialog
- button on map

How can I learn how to do.

Comment: You need to be way more specific, please at least try to finf your answer on google first...

Comment: I want to make a map like this and I tried to find it on google but did not meet the requirements. so I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple jquery work.

for **popup dialog** you can check the [custom popup](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/) link that work on mouse over on marker.

**Button on map** is just some images in background and numbers are show on above of that.
check [change marker image tutorial](http://nhw.pl/wp/2007/09/19/changing-markers-icons-with-google-maps-api)

**sidebar** is just trick that work on mouse over on map and hide the side div and increase the length of map.
 [Examples are here](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

similarly i think **icon loading marker** is also a image the loading is showing on mouseover event.